# how to print values in already designed A4 paper in Java?

Tags: java, printing

I'm creating Web App using Java,And one of the tasks is to print a report to the customer.The problem is that the paper design is already made and putted in the actual printer and I must only fill the blank fields.The questions are :
1) how can I print the values exactly in the fields ?
2) Is there a way to simulate this process without having physical printer, like using virtual printer and upload the default page to it ?

I attached part of the paper that will be in the printer and I should fill the blank fields with data comes from JSF page.

[image]

Comment: Is the paper "official"? Because it would be a lot easier to just print all that out on a blank paper instead of trying to get the text in correct places.

Comment: Unfortunately the paper is official and i must fill blanks my self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem like yours in the past. My company has a pre-designed printed invoice. My task is to put the data into the blanks in place. In my experience, you should:

- Scan the paper into an image with the same size as the physical version.
- Measure the distance from a blank to another.
- Specify the location of the blanks to output the data based on your measurement.
- You can use the digitalized version as the background of the output page and test on it.
- Try to put the first blank in place.
- Test and adjust your code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the things that are there in the page only in the soft copy you can do one thing. Design a A4 exactly the same way you have on the printed page. Then write down variables in the places where you would like to fill up from your java program. That docx file will act as the template. After that, replace those texts with the actual values from the Java program in that template. All these can be done with [docx4j api](http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.pdf).

A code block like this will be useful :

```
if (textElement.getValue().contains(placeholder)) {  
    String temp = textElement.getValue();
    temp = temp.replace(placeholder, name);
    textElement.setValue(temp);  
    return;
  }
```

This is how we do it our project. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i will try it and let you know.